# Facebook Graph API: Attend to event always returns responseCode: 200, false

Tags: java, android, events, facebook-graph-api, post

I'm trying to Attend a facebook user to an event, with

```
Request.executePostRequestAsync(...)
```

but the server always returns with the following:

```
{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphObject, state={"FACEBOOK_NON_JSON_RESULT":false}}, error: null, isFromCache:false}
```

The authentication works, I can get the user infos, etc... I tried laso my link with the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=354295554671715/attending) and it worked there, so something should be wrong with my code.
I checked also my permissions, they are allright.
I'd be pleased if someone could help me, here is my code:

```
List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
permissions.add("rsvp_event");

private void attendToEvent(final String eventID){
    Session.openActiveSession(MainActivity.this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

            Session actSession = Session.getActiveSession();
            if (!hasRSVPEventPermission() && actSession.isOpened()) {
                actSession.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(MainActivity.this, permissions));
            }

            String accessToken = actSession.getAccessToken();
            String path = new String("https://graph.facebook.com/"+eventID+"/attending");
            if(session != null && session.isOpened()){
                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
                final GraphObject go = GraphObject.Factory.create(jo);
                Request.executePostRequestAsync(session, path, go, new Request.Callback() {
                //Request.executeGraphPathRequestAsync(session, path, new Request.Callback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        System.out.println(response.toString());
                        showAttendResult(response.getGraphObject(), response.getError());
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}

private boolean hasRSVPEventPermission() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    return session != null && session.getPermissions().contains("rsvp_event");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it out!
The problem was, the instead of this path:

```
String path = new String("https://graph.facebook.com/"+eventID+"/attending");
```

the Graph API expects this:

```
String path = new String(eventID+"/attending");
```

So without the "http://graph.facebook.com/" !